# How to permanently join 2 cut Pergo pieces?

Tags: flooring

I want to permanently two Pergo pieces to make a longer piece. Could I simply use wood glue for this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

jut cut a tongue into one and a groove in the other.  glue and you are done

Comment: I'm not that good with carpentry. Is there a special tool you can use for that?

Comment: there are many special tools you can use, all of them exceedingly dangerous in the hands of someone "not that good with carpentry".  instead of buying a few hundred dollars worth of chisels and planes or routers and bits, just take it to a local wood shop and ask them to do it for you.  it probably wont cost more than $50-$100, and it will avoid any trips to the emergency room

Comment: in retrospect, if you want to go slow and do it yourself, it could be done with  a handsaw and a wood file (for the groove), and a speed square and a good olfa type knife.  just go slow and use a good table to hold it steady.  good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use wood glue.  Try a non-water based adhesive to avoid swelling, and T & G the joint as mentioned by others.